# How to search for a match, then a non-match on that line, but include context lines for matched line?

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, gnu

Say I have a file containing:

```
⟫ cat schema.rb 
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "other_column"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
  end

  create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.citext "email"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 0
  end
```

and I want to find all lines matching `created_at` but *not* matching `precision:`. That's easy enough:

```
⟫ grep created_at schema.rb 
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 0

⟫ grep created_at schema.rb | grep -v precision:
    t.datetime "created_at"
```

but what if I want to get some context lines for the matched lines so I can see which `create_table` block they occurred in? Adding a `-C`/`-B` flag to the final `grep -v` is too late because the first grep already dropped all context lines.

```
⟫ grep created_at schema.rb | grep -v precision: -B3
    t.datetime "created_at"
```

But adding it to the first `grep` is too early because the `grep -v` only removes its matched line, not the context lines around its matched lines:

```
⟫ grep created_at -B3 schema.rb | grep -v precision: -B3
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "other_column"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
--
  create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.citext "email"
    # ...
```

Is there any way to get it to only include the context lines for the matched lines from the first `grep` (or equivalently, get the `grep -v` to remove the context lines around its matched lines)?

```
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "other_column"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
```

Or is there another command that would do this for me?

(a simple `sed` script perhaps—if it requires anything more than a *simple* `sed` script, I may as well write it in `ruby` so that it's easier to read and maintain).

Comment: If you want blank-line separated *records* matching / not matching the two strings you could just use awk in paragraph mode e.g. `awk -vRS= '/created_at/ && !/precision/' schema.rb`

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks! Yes, that does look like it would work in this case since the `create_table` sections are all separated by a blank line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what I was trying to do is possible if I chain together 2 `grep` commands (since the context lines are relative to each individual `grep` command).

It occurred to me that a negative lookahead might be what I want. Then it could all be done with a single `grep` command.

To my surprise, it looks like GNU `grep` actually does have support for regex lookbehind/lookahead — but only if you use the `--perl-regex` option.

Here's a `grep` command that gives me what I was looking for:

```
⟫ grep --perl-regexp 'created_at(?!(.*precision:))' schema.rb -B3
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "other_column"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
```

Answer (score 0):

**awk solution**

```
$ awk '/create_table/,/created_at/&&!/precision:/' schema.rb
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "other_column"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at"
  create_table "users", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.citext "email"
    # ...
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 0
  end
$
```

None of these below achieve *exactly* what you're after, but I'll throw them in, in case useful in some way.

**sed solution that prints the create_table line and the match**

Look for create_table line, if found, store in holding buffer 'h'.
Look for created_at followed by precision, if found, ignore it.
Look for created_at alone, if found, print it.

```
$ sed -n '/create_table/h;/created_at.*precision:/d;/created_at/{H;g;p}' schema.rb
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
$
```

**awk solution that prints the create_table line and the match**

If you specifically wanted the create_table line against the match, you could use

```
$ awk '/create_table/{t=$0}/created_at/&&!/precision:/{print t"\n"$0}' schema.rb
  create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
$
```

**awk solution that prints the table**

Taking it a little further, if you wanted just the table names which had a matching line within, you could use

```
$ awk '/create_table/{t=$2}/created_at/&&!/precision:/{print substr(t,2,length(t)-3)}' schema.rb
things
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't simply reversing the two `grep`s do what you want, eliminating the `precision` lines upfront so they won't match the `created_at` lines in the second `grep`?

```
grep -v precision schema.rb | grep -A1 -B3 created_at 
create_table "things", id: :serial, force: :cascade do |t|
   t.string "other_column"
   # ...
   t.datetime "created_at"
 end
```